# Swagger resteasy classloader issue

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader, swagger, resteasy

I am triing to document a rest service with swagger. After build and deploy I get a json, that is lacking the tags (in my case `"tags" : ["databases"]` is missing) and completely ignores the annotations on the parameters of the webservice interface methods (only the parameters, other documetation is provided correctly). Instead of listing the parameters it contains this:

```
"parameters" : [{
                    "in" : "body",
                    "name" : "body",
                    "required" : false,
                    "schema" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                    }
                }
            ]
```

Most likely it has someting to do with the configuration or the process of loading the webapplication, since after a reload of the webapplication with the tomcat manager webapp it sends the correct json.

**EDIT: Simply stopping and restarting the application has the same effect. In addion the json after a reload or restart is not deterministic (random). This implies the problem should be with the classloader.**

I am using apache tomcat version 8.0.33, the resteasy version is `3.0.14.Final` and the swagger is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8</version>
</dependency>
```

The application class looks like:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class ServiceApplication extends Application {

final Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

public ServiceApplication() throws IOException {
    final InputStream inStream = getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("swagger.properties");
    final Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(inStream);

    final BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
    beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.0");
    beanConfig.setHost(props.getProperty("host"));
    beanConfig.setBasePath("/rest-service");
    beanConfig.setResourcePackage("com.example.package");
    beanConfig.setScan(true);

    final CorsFilter filter = new CorsFilter();
    filter.getAllowedOrigins().add("*");
    singletons.add(filter);

}

@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    final Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    // add WS classes
    resources.add(DatabasesImpl.class);

    // add provider classes
    resources.add(ExcMapper1.class);
    resources.add(ExcMapper2.class);
    resources.add(ResponseInterceptor.class);
    // add swagger classes
    resources.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
    resources.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class);
    return resources;
}

@Override
public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
    return singletons;
}
}
```

The annotations on the webservice:

```
@SwaggerDefinition(info = @io.swagger.annotations.Info(description = "<DESCRIPTION>",//
version = "0.0.2-SNAPSHOT", title = "Search", termsOfService = "<TOS>",//
contact = @io.swagger.annotations.Contact(name = "<CONTACT_NAME>", email = "<CONTACT_EMAIL>", url = "<CONTACT_URL>"),//
license = @io.swagger.annotations.License(name = "<LICENCE_NAME>", url = "<LICENCE_URL>")), consumes = {}, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML },//
schemes = { SwaggerDefinition.Scheme.HTTP, SwaggerDefinition.Scheme.HTTPS },//
externalDocs = @io.swagger.annotations.ExternalDocs(value = "<EXTERNAL_DOCS>", url = "<EXTERNAL_DOCS_URL>"))
@Api(value = "/databases")
@Path("/databases/")
public interface Databases {

@ApiOperation(value = "Searches the database")
@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Database not found") })
@GET
@Path("{database}/search")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response searchExport(
        @ApiParam(value = "the database name", required = true,  defaultValue = "default") @PathParam("database") @Nonnull final String database,
        @ApiParam(value = "query string defaults to match all", defaultValue = "title:foo") @QueryParam("q") @DefaultValue("*:*") final String query,
        @ApiParam(value = "starting element index defaults to 0") @QueryParam("start") @DefaultValue("0") final int start,
        @ApiParam(value = "number of elements to return defaults to 10") @QueryParam("rows") @DefaultValue("10") final int rows,
        @ApiParam(value = "sorting field") @QueryParam("sort") @DefaultValue("title") final String sort,
        @ApiParam(value = "sorting order defaults to ascending") @QueryParam("sortOrder") @DefaultValue("ascending") final SortDirection sortOrder)
                throws ParseException;
```

Comment: Where are you adding the `databases` tag?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin I am using the `@Api(value = "/databases")` anntotation on the webservice interface definition, but according to the documentation, `@Api(tags = ...` should be also ok.

Comment: Please, consider posting this part of code. It's relevant for your question.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin I added that part to the question. Although I doubt this kind of behavior may have something to do with tohose annotations. For me it looks more like a problem with webservice loading or swagger loading, since after a simple reload (no other change) it runs fine.

Comment: Do you get any stack trace at the first load? If yes, could you provide that?

Comment: @SampadaWagde no, not a single one.

Comment: Ok. This might seem weird but i was facing similar (not same) issue. Changing the jackson provider from JacksonJaxbJsonProvider to JacksonJsonProvider worked for me.

Comment: @SampadaWagde could you please elaborate it a bit more? For your webservice or for the swagger? How did you set it?

Comment: For the restFul web services, in the spring bean configuration where you define the beans for the providers.

Comment: @SampadaWagde The only providers I defined are the exception mappers and the interceptor. But even when I remove them, I get the same behavior.